# Most compact way to serialize an object that contains other objects in python?

Tags: python, json, class, object, serialization

What is the most compact way to serialize an object that contains other objects or even nested collections of other objects in python?

**More info:**

In my project, I have collections of instances of my own classes, and each some of these classes again contain collections of instances of some of my other classes.

I need to transfer some of these collections through a REST api using json files.

We can use an example like below.

**Example Code:**

```
from typing import List, Dict


class Organization:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.employees = []  # type: List[Person]


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name
        self.qualification = ""
        self.pets = []  # type: List[Pet]


class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name: str, species: str):
        self.species = species
        self.name = name


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pets_dict = {"Simba": "cat", "Winnie": "bear", "Tigger": "bear", "Drogon": "dragon",
                "Rhaegal": "dragon", "Viserion":"dragon",  "Ghost": "wolf"}
    people_dict = ["Walt", "Christopher", "Dany", "Jon"]
    pets_obj = {p: Pet(p, pets_dict[p]) for p in pets_dict}  # type: Dict[str, Pet]
    people_obj = {p: Person(p) for p in people_dict}  # type: Dict[str, Person]
    people_obj["Walt"].pets = [pets_obj["Simba"],]
    people_obj["Christopher"].pets = [pets_obj["Winnie"], pets_obj["Tigger"]]
    people_obj["Dany"].pets = [pets_obj["Drogon"], pets_obj["Rhaegal"], pets_obj["Viserion"]]
    people_obj["Jon"].pets = [pets_obj["Ghost"], ]
    organization = Organization("Stories")
    organization.employees = list(people_obj.values())

    print(vars(organization))
```

**Output:**

```
{'name': 'Stories', 'employees': [<__main__.Person object at 0x00000000025DFDD8>, <__main__.Person object at 0x00000000025E6630>,  <__main__.Person object at 0x00000000025E6AC8>, <__main__.Person object at 0x00000000025E6B38>]}
```

As we can see, only the highest level of the object has been serialized, while the objects inside any of its collection keep their type.

**Solutions Found So Far:**

1. There is [this question-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable).
   It contains 2 suggestions: The first is for simple cases only, by using `dumps(organization.__dict__)`. This does not work in the example case. The second method is to write an encoding class, which is similar to the solution (2) below. It's not a bad solution, but see my "Why I think there should be a better way" below.
2. Use json.dump (or dumps) and include a serializer for each custom class.

   ```
   def my_serializer(obj):
       if type(obj) in (Organization, Person, Pet):
           return vars(obj)
       else:
           return obj
   ```

then do

```
    print(dumps(organization, default=my_serializer))
```

3. Write a self.export method for each class, which will serialize itself, and for any collections of custom classes it contains, call the export method of that class when serializing.

**Why I think there should be a better way:**

Essentially I am looking for a deep `vars` (like there is a `deepcopy`). I can imagine that there are many who have wanted such a thing, so I expect a simple and clear solution exists. I just couldn't Google my way to it, so I turn to the community.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 - passing a serialiser to `json.dumps` - is the right way to do this.  You provide the serialiser, `json.dumps` handles recursing through the object graph.

There's no value in `deep_vars` unless you want a dictionary of your object graph, but you don't want a dictionary, you just the json.

Comment: Thanks! I agree. Just for my education: if I did want a dictionary of my object graph, is there a way to do it?